# Alsa and gnome aren't cooperating

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, audio, alsa

I have an image of debian 8, with gnome de, and the audio doesn't want to work. Gnome's default mixer doesn't seem to be working, while alsamixer shows my audio card, correctly, and 'speaker-test' outputs sound to the audio card.
Since alsamixer managed to detect the audio card, and the same audio card worked with no further drivers whatsoever before, I suppose it's not a driver problem. Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the cause of the problem. I used a persistent /home partition, therefore settings where kept across the different distributions of linux I have installed. At some point I have broken the configuration.
I removed the faulty configuration files from my home directory, and everything started working properly.